# How can this in condition be modified so that it can replace infinite and NaN values?

Tags: c#

I'm using a library for real-time plotting of an FFT of an incoming array. FFT of the array includes NaNs or infinites and this causes error in plot.

To overcome that I came across the following if conditional filter which checks NaNs and infinites in the FFT array (MyArray) and performs plotting only there are no NaNs and infinities:

```
if (!MyArray.Cast<double>().AsParallel().Any(d => double.IsNaN(d) || double.IsInfinity(d) || double.IsNegativeInfinity(d)))
   {
        //Plot the array
   }
```

But the above skips plotting if there are elements of the array as infinities or NaNs. How can this be achieved such that of all infinites and NaNs are replaced by zeroes?

**edit:** The plot function uses the same array as input. The input to the plot function has to be an array. I use Scott Plot. It has a methods called AddScatter or Signal which both requires double array or two double arrays as input arguments. I don't need MyArray still has NaNs and infinities after plotting. It is very okay to modify directly.

Comment: We don't know what the code for "Plot the array" needs, which makes it hard to give a concrete answer. Does it need an array? Just an `IEnumerable<double>`? Something else?

Comment: You see MyArray in the if condition. The plot function uses the same array as input. So in my case MyArray is checked and if there are any NaN or infinite element in the array no plot is updated. But I want in such case to replace the NaNs and infinites with zeroes so a plot still can be shown.

Comment: If you mean the type of the array, MyArray is a double array declared as double[] MyArray.

Comment: "The plot function uses the same array as input." That was what I was asking about. But does it *have* to be an array? What method are you calling, and what are its parameter types? And do you need `MyArray` to still have the NaNs and infinities after plotting, or would it be okay to modify the array directly?

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes it has to be an array. I use Scott Plot. It has a methods called AddScatter or Signal which both requires double array or two double arrays as input arguments. I don't need MyArray still has NaNs and infinities after plotting. It is very okay to modify directly.

Comment: Okay - I'll add an answer, but please edit your question (for future readers) to give all of that information.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I added the info on comments to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just iterate through your array and replace anything that's infinite or NaN:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < MyArray.Length; i++)
{
    double d = MyArray[i];
    // Note that IsInfinity handles both positive and negative.
    if (double.IsNaN(d) || double.IsInfinity(d))
    {
        MyArray[i] = 0d;
    }
}
```

If you're using .NET Core 2.1 or higher (or .NET 5 or higher) then you can just use `double.IsFinite`:

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < MyArray.Length; i++)
{
    double d = MyArray[i];
    if (!double.IsFinite(MyArray[i]))
    {
        MyArray[i] = 0d;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your second version check for NaNs?

Comment: @GNZ: Yes, otherwise I wouldn't have suggested it.